# SonataAdmin preBatch Event for usage in listener/subscriber

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Is there any option to catch the sonata batch action inside subscriber/listener ?

Already tried to use something like
**sonata.admin.event.persistence.pre_batch**, but it doesn't work

**Why I need that ?**

When user will batch delete entities which contains images (there is working custom uploader sys behind it), then I should delete all images from fileSystem also.

**My current configuration**

(**Everything works here** and I want to also add pre_batch event, but so far no success)

```
    image.uploader.subscriber:
    class: AdminBundle\EventListener\ImageUploaderSubscriber
    arguments:
        - '@image.remover'
        - '@image.uploader'
    tags:
        - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: sonata.admin.event.persistence.pre_persist, method: prePersist}
        - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: sonata.admin.event.persistence.pre_update, method: preUpdate}
        - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: sonata.admin.event.persistence.pre_remove, method: preRemove}
```

Seems like hook for this event is not implemented, as it's only possible to call it from Admin Class.

So, maybe there is option to create Event by myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonata admin model manager (used by batch delete) is actually iterating over entities. So you could hook inside doctrine lifecycle callbacks and do your logic there.

But in general `preBatch` action doesn't trigger any event, but you still can override this `preBatchAction` in your admin class and trigger your event from there.

Comment: This time overriding in admin class won't work, because I need upload system which works automatically.

About first one. Yeah, seems like thats the only way. I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Yeah, I managed to do what I need by creating preRemoveListener. 

Then i use the request data, because sonata actually sends ids what it deletes, or bool (all_elements).